# why is my training output printing irregularly?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am training my CNN using the following code:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
        train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=int(np.ceil(train_data_gen.n / float(batch_size))),
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data=val_data_gen,
        validation_steps=int(np.ceil(val_data_gen.n / float(batch_size))),
        verbose=1,
    )
```

and these are the output:

[image: training output]

The accuracy is okay but why is epoch 1/20 repeating itself multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps per epoch is not managed well. You are trying to validate twice too..

Try without the `float` and `int`:

```
history = model.fit_generator(
        train_data_gen,
        steps_per_epoch=np.ceil(train_data_gen.n / batch_size),
        epochs=num_epochs,
        validation_data=val_data_gen,
        validation_steps=np.ceil(val_data_gen.n / batch_size),
        verbose=1,
    )
```

print out the values of generator size, the `steps_per_epoch` should reflect number of training steps (usually determined by generator function)

And make sure `train_data_gen.n = total_training_samples` and same for `val_data_gen.n = total_validation_samples`

OR, just comment out `steps_per_epoch` and `validation_steps` and the model will take on the generator length as training steps.

Consult: https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator